# EditText receives nothing from the Custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have been using AlertDialog class to show a Custom Dialog(forgot_password.xml) and then receiving the input from the Custom Dialog box. In order to fetch the inputs from the edittext I have used layoutinflator but it receives nothing from the field. I used toast message to verify the user input. And one more thing Dialog class we can use dismiss() to close the Dialog similarly for AlertDialog What i've to do?

Below is my forgot_password.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/grey"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/tv_3rd_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_3rd_username"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/et_2nd_hint_name"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ib_delete_text"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:src="@drawable/cancel_circle" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_3rd_emailid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/et_2nd_hint_email"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ib_delete_text"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:src="@drawable/cancel_circle" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_3rd_close"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_states"
                    android:text="@string/btn_1st_exit" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_3rd_send"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_states"
                    android:text="@string/btn_3rd_send" />
            </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

following is my AlertDialog coding used it in MainActivity's onCreateDialog() inside a switch case

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args) {
    Dialog d = null;
    switch(id){
case R.id.ib_1st_forgot:
    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //used layout inflator to fetch user input from forgot_password.xml
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.forgot_password, null);
    ab.setView(ll);
    d = ab.create();
    //forgot_password.xml file's buttons and edittext
    Button send_link = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.btn_3rd_send);
    Button close_dlg = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.btn_3rd_close);
    EditText e_name = (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.et_3rd_username);
    EditText e_email = (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.et_3rd_emailid);
    final String names = e_name.getText().toString();
    final String emails = e_email.getText().toString();
    send_link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "username is "+names, 0).show();
        }
    });
    close_dlg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //need a dialog close operation here
        }
    });
    break;
    }
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the location of the following two lines:

```
final String names = e_name.getText().toString();
final String emails = e_email.getText().toString();
```

They get executed right after inflating the views, which makes little sense. In stead, what you probably want, is to get those values when one of the `OnClickListener`s gets hit. So basically move them down into `onClick()`:

```
final EditText e_name = (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.et_3rd_username);
final EditText e_email = (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.et_3rd_emailid);
send_link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String names = e_name.getText().toString();
        String emails = e_email.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "username is "+names, 0).show();
    }
});
```

> And one more thing Dialog class we can use dismiss() to close the Dialog similarly for AlertDialog

Yes, sure. Just call `d.dismiss()` to manually dismiss the dialog you're creating.

Comment: Thanks bro @MH. . I got it. But for 'AlertDialog.Builder' I don't receive any 'dismiss()' method when i'm saying 'ab.dismiss();' it shows error. except this method everythings working fine

Comment: You've also got a `Dialog d`, which gets assigned the result of the `AlertDialog.Builder`. So as I said, just call `d.dismiss()` if you want to dismiss the dialog.